# Does OFBIZ Support C#?

Tags: c#, ofbiz

Please anybody knows whether `OFBIZ` supports `C#` or not?
Please reply me as soon as possible.

---

*and (merged)*

---

My friend create an desktop (client) & server side application in `C#.net`.
But the organization now said to him change the technology from `C#` `.net` to `ofbiz`.

He already created a window application in `C#`. But he doesn't know how to switch to `ofbiz`. Thus `ofbi`z support `C#`.

We want to integrate my `C#` Application with `OFBIZ` framework.
Please post your suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Support in what sense - what are you trying to do with it? It looks like it's written in Java, as I expect you know.

Comment: I hate the word **urgent** in sites like SO. Why should anyone treat your question differently? It's not like you pay for the answer.

Comment: sorry for that...do not use it again...

Comment: Suggestions? The client is always right.

Comment: So... Changing from a custom app to a pre-canned "enterprise solution". I suspect "stop coding, start configuring/integrating" goes a long way to describe things. Any customizations are very unlikely to be in c#, so you might also want to learn their API and supported toolset.

Comment: Mac gravell thanks for ur reply.I cannot understand ur words so please xplain it.

Comment: Telling somebody who writes good English that you don't understand his words while having half a dozen mistakes in your own sentence strikes me as slightly ironic.

Comment: I've re-read it, and I don't think I've used any complex/unusual phrasing. If that is a struggle, reading the ofbiz documentation is going to be hard work.

Comment: @sivakumar.j ofbiz is written in java (enterprise java application)

Comment: Thanks Marc Gravell... My problem is exactly what you said

Comment: Here we go, closed as dupliate. OfBiz is a nice keyword if one bothers to do a search. The answer there also has the one way how to integrate. Whether this is feasible for the problem at hand is not our decision given that this is a "do my job, NOW, without pay, I am clueless" question - especialyl given that we do not even know what integration is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make API / Web services calls via SOAP from C#.

Useful PDF about it:
http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/OFBIZ_SOAP_RMI_Tutorial.pdf

Comment: Thanks Chris Ledet... Could you please tell me what you mean API here? and Shall i run OFBIZ with my C# Application? Is it possible?

Comment: Check out that link I posted above. You need both OFbiz and your C# app to communicate so how. You can do this via web services.

Comment: @Saravanan: You need to host your OFBiz app separately from your C# app. Then you call the C# API from the OFBiz service layer using SOAP protocol. Since you're not currently skilled at doing this, I'd suggest you try not to.

Comment: Thanks Jose...but i have one doubt.Is there any way to put my server side c# files inside the OFBIZ hot-deploy folder and able to run it?suppose my question don't make any sense Please suggest me your thoughts

Comment: @Saravanan: No you cant do that since hot-deploy is only for web apps coded as per J2EE & OFBiz specs, which is not the case with C# apps. So the two won't mix. You'll have to recode the entire C# thing as an OFBiz app. So the only feasible option is to see if web service communication is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have come to cleared mind jose...could you please tell your thoughts about my final question.I have found one Apache Plug in NMAVEN.Basically i heard, NMaven is an extension of Maven, providing support for building of .NET applications(interface with build tools (compilers, unit test tools, etc.) for any other languages including C#).So,Can we put this plug-in into OFBIZ and able to solve my problem that i already told in my previous comments...

Comment: @Saravanan: I dont have a clue about NMaven so cant help there

Comment: OK JOSE... I will try to get it if possible... Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 5):

Even I don't know what is the right meaning of "Support C#" in you question!, But I can tell you that you can't use C# with ofBiz in any way .

Comment: i have C# desktop application and now i want to integrate this C# application with OFBIZ framework.Is this possible or not...

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.But Please give me reason about your thoughts.

Comment: I want to document about my reason why we cann't integrate C# Application with OFBIZ...